# MATLAB structures seem to be slow

Tags: matlab, performance, function, structure

In my code I have to pass several large arrays to a function and in order to simplify the readability I use a structure, and I call it `params`. Specifically:

```
params.grid1 = grid1;
params.grid2 = grid2; % these are big arrays
% etc.

% Define x

y = myfun(x,params)


function y = myfun(x,params)
   y = x+params.grid2;
end
```

I noticed however that the following code below is much faster:

```
params.grid1 = grid1;
params.grid2 = grid2; % these are big arrays
% etc.

% Define x

y = x+params.grid2;
```

It seems that the function call in the first version of the code significantly slows down the performance. Unfortunately for my project I can't avoid using functions (it would otherwise be a mess). I thought that passing structures to a function was a fast option. Any suggestion about how to improve speed?

HERE IS A MWE:

```
%% Passing matlab structures to function seems to be slow

clear;clc;close all

n = 100000;

rng('default')
grid1 = rand(n,1);
grid2 = rand(n,1);
params.grid1 = grid1;
params.grid2 = grid2; % these are big arrays
% etc.
% Define x
%% disp('Testing code 1 - passing struct to a function')
tic
x = 3;
[y1,y2] = myfun(x,params);
y1
y2
toc

%% disp('Testing code 2 - no function')
tic

x = 3;
y1 = mean(x+(params.grid1).^2);
y2 = mean(x+(params.grid2).^2);



 y1
 y2

toc
```

To run it you also need the function below:

```
function [y1,y2] = myfun(x,params)
   y1 = mean(x+(params.grid1).^2);
   y2 = mean(x+(params.grid2).^2);


end
```

Code 1 (passing struct to function): Elapsed time is 0.001682 seconds.
Code 2 (NO passing struct to function): Elapsed time is 0.000737 seconds.

Before testing, I ran the code a couple of times as suggested.

Comment: If you really want speed, avoid structures. Also, can you make a [mcve] that shows this behavior? How did you measure speed?

Comment: To measure speed I used tic toc

Comment: Please, show us a [mcve]

Comment: Hi Alessandro, if each of your grid have the same size you could create a matrix of dimension n+1 (where n is the dimension of your grids)

Comment: To measure speed, don't use `tic`, `toc`. That is very innacurate and can be misleading. Always stick the code to be timed into a function (so the JIT can do its thing) and use `timeit` to time the function execution. `timeit` will run the function multiple times, and in a way that the compilation time doesn't affect the timing.

Comment: In particular, the first time you call a function, it will be loaded and compiled, which incurs a time penalty. The second time the function is called it will be much faster. So at least run the function once before timing it with your `tic`/`toc` construct.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I included a MWE

Comment: @CrisLuengo I'm aware of the JIT, indeed before registering the execution time I ran the code a couple of times, to allow precompilation. Could u please suggest how to use timeit in my code above (see new version with the mwe)?

Comment: Create a function M-file, with two private functions: `method1` and `method2`. They both need to take in the `x` and `params` arrays, and return the `y1` and `y2` arrays. In the main function, do `timeit(@()method1(x,params))` and `timeit(@()method2(x,params))`. That will give you a good idea of the overhead of calling a function.

Comment: You might want to add a 3rd function in your test, to see if `myfun(x,params)` really is slower than `myfun(x,grid1,grid2)`.